# regex: querying full name with partial query from user input

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongodb

I have an input field in which a user can search for people and I'd like them to be able to query by a combination of partial first and last name without spaces.

So `josm` should result in a match on `John Smith`.

I'm performing this search via a mongo query over a field of `fullName`.

Is this possible with regex or some other javascript/node/mongo related approach?

Edit:
This is for a typeahead that should return all possible matches.

Comment: Should `josm` match `Jane Osmosis` or `Jay Oswald Mackenzie`?

Comment: sorry, should have been more specific, but it's for a typeahead that will give them a list of all possible matches.  so yes

Comment: Then just add `.*` after each character and prepend it to the regex as well. `.*j.*o.*s.*m.*`

Comment: yeah, that works, thanks!